# Thymeleaf's form dont return the object to controller class's method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, thymeleaf, h2

I have a SpringBoot-MVC Java application with JPA/Hibernate, using a H2 database to store data and I'm trying to read and change lines of this database through web browser. I had success with the reading, but the edit page's form with thymeleaf does not send the object I alterated to controller class.

The formulary:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Cadastro de Clientes</title>
<link href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Edicao de Clientes</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${customer}"
                th:action="@{/save}" method="post" style="margin: 10px">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}">
                                <div th:each="detailedError : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}">
                                    <span th:text="${detailedError.message}"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm"
                                    th:field="*{id}" readonly="readonly" style="display: none;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <label>CÓD. DO CLIENTE</label> <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{customerId}"
                                    readonly="readonly" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('companyName')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>RAZAO SOCIAL</label> <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{companyName}"
                                    autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Informe o texto"
                                    maxlength="50" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('tradeName')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>NOME FANTASIA</label> <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{tradeName}"
                                    maxlength="150" placeholder="Informe o texto" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('sectorId')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>SETOR</label> <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{sectorId}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('neighborhood')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>BAIRRO</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm"
                                    th:field="*{neighborhood}" placeholder="Informe o texto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('place')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>LOGRADOURO</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{place}"
                                    placeholder="Informe o texto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('neighborhood')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>NUMERO</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{placeId}"
                                    placeholder="Informe o texto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('city')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>CIDADE</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{city}"
                                    placeholder="Informe o texto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('visitDay')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>DIA DE VISITA</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{visitDay}"
                                    placeholder="Informe o texto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('region')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>REGIAO</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{region}"
                                    placeholder="Informe o texto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('latitude')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>LATITUDE</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{latitude}"
                                    placeholder="Informe o texto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('longitude')}? 'has-error'">
                                <label>LONGITUDE</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{longitude}"
                                    placeholder="Informe o texto"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                            <a th:href="@{/}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Cancelar</a>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The method that should receive the object of formulary:

```
package com.br.aloi.planner.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.br.aloi.planner.model.Customer;
import com.br.aloi.planner.service.CustomerService;

@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService service;

(...)

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ModelAndView save(@Valid Customer customer, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return edit(customer.getId());
        }
        service.save(customer);
        return findAll();
    }

}
```

The objects is returning null to the `save` method on controller class. Otherwise when I select a line of the database in browser and click on 'edit', the edit page open for edition with the attributes of objects created just perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before demanding an object from Thymeleaf you have to pass the object via your model for Thymeleaf to have it.

Add the following to your controller method:

```
@ModelAttribute("customer")
public Customer thisPartCanBeCalledWhatever() {
    return new Customer(); 
}
```

Make sure Customer class has getters, setters and default constructor.

Comment: @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
 public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/customerEdit");
  mv.addObject("customer", service.findById(id));
  return mv;
 }

Comment: I send the object using the addObject inside the edit method. isnt wrong?

Comment: well you code seems to think so, it returns you null:) The only way to know is to try my advice and see if it helps. Try also displaying in themeleaf the customer object for debuggin purposes. Important is that in any case when that page loads the customer object is already in the model and i don't know if that is the case in your code. With my method we make sure of that.

Comment: As you commanded, I recheck my model class and discover that unique 'id customer.Id' isnt with the setter declared, only the getter. Resolv the problem. Thank so much Asgarov, and sorry my ignorance.

Comment: no ignorance whatsoever, it is very common to forget getters or setters, happy it worked out:)

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of J Asgarov, i recheck my model and i recreate the getters and setters of all attributes. After rebuild the project, the post was returned the object instantly. The code was correct after all, my newbie that was disturbing
afterall. Thanks !!